# Telerik Kendo DropDownList has the previous value on select event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a simple Kendo MVC dropdown and all I want to do is get the correct value, this javascript pulls the previous value and I don't understand why.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("TextActionDDL")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:25%" })
            .OptionLabel("Select text message...")
            .DataTextField("TxtMessage")
            .DataValueField("TxtMessageText")
            .Events(x => x.Select("updateTextMsgBox"))
            .Height(310)
            .DataSource(source =>
            {
                source.Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("Overview_Get_TextMessages", "Home");
                });
            })
        )




 public JsonResult Overview_Get_TextMessages()
        {
            var northwind = new List<Models.TxtMessageModel>();
            northwind.Add(new Models.TxtMessageModel() { TxtMessage = "Needing Capitial",TxtMessageText = "Yo u need cap?" });
            northwind.Add(new Models.TxtMessageModel() { TxtMessage = "Follow Up on Loan Application", TxtMessageText = "You need answer me." });


            northwind = northwind.OrderBy(x => x.TxtMessage).ToList();
            return Json(northwind, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

function updateTextMsgBox(e) {
    alert($("#TextActionDDL").data("kendoDropDownList").text());
    alert($("#TextActionDDL").val());
}
```

So what I'm saying is on page load and on the first selection if I choose "Needing Capitial" I get the OptionLabel `Select text message...`.  On each additional dropdown selection I get the previous option that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the event to Change, it works fine